# Previous items piling up in the Listview

Tags: android, listview

I've created a listview which takes the input from the alertDialog editText and populate it. Everything is working fine but after deleting the item from the row and adding something again it adds up the previous deleted item also which is not a good thing. I know the clear picture of my problem but it is difficult to find out whether how to do that.

This is my code where I'm adding the list inside the listView :

**Adding Items**

```
{ items[items.length - 1] = value;

                List<String> newList = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(items));

                //Log.e("STRIING", newArray.toString());

                adapter = new MyListAdapter(RecyclerActivity.this, newList);
                mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                String[] temp = new String[items.length + 1];

                for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
                    temp[i] = items[i];

                items = temp;

                alertDialog.dismiss();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                input.getText().clear();
            }
```

In here I have to notify the changes of the deleted item in order to get the desired result but i don't know how.

Here is the place where I'm deleting the item from the listview:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            final String pos = mListView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            Log.e("POS", pos);

            deleteDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    adapter.remove(pos);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            deleteDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

and here is the MyAdapter class  which binds the data :

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private final Context context;
    private final List<String> values;

    class ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;
    }


    public MyListAdapter(Context context, List<String> newList) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_item, newList);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = newList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvItem);
        textView.setText(values.get(position));
        return rowView;
    }


}
```

**My adapter is the Global Variable**

I've tried using this in order to see whether the problem is getting fixed or not by following this link :

[Deleting the items for the listview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18837858/8462903)

The code looked like this now . :

```
newList.remove(pos);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

newList is nothing but a **List<> of type String**

Please help me with this because I have wasted a long hour in this only. Thanks in advance.

**EDITS**

**I've tried adding this in my Adapter Class, but this is giving me the same result :**

```
public void removeItem(String position) {
        values.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

**Calling this method like this**

```
adapter.removeItem(pos);
```

But same result

**SOLVED**

I've solved this problem by defining the single ArrayList in Global and using it. Made my work easy.

**In my add section I've changed it like this**

```
{ 
            newArrayList.add(value);
            adapter = new MyListAdapter(RecyclerActivity.this, newList);
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

            String[] temp = new String[items.length + 1];

            for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
                temp[i] = items[i];

            items = temp;

            alertDialog.dismiss();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            input.getText().clear();
        }
```

Just creation of single variable as the array works smoothly.

Comment: attach screenshot of  your output

Comment: okay I'll do that

Comment: Did that @Ankita